# Order in jQuery calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

I have a *jQuery* loop that iterates over specifics elements of an *HTML* page. For every element, I do a *switch* over a variable and append *HTML* code in specific places.

The problem is that, one of those appends is an import to another *Javascript* file. This file uses a variable from the first one but, for some reason, that variable doesn't always have the correct value, depending on the order of the *HTML* elements in the page.

> **UPDATE**
>
> As requested, I created a Plunker so it's easy to see code:
>   http://plnkr.co/edit/mrEhgbZhhvu0Z4iniXGl?p=preview
>
> **Note**: For this to work, you need to have correct ***pageId*** and ***appId*** for Instagram.

I'll put the code to be more clear:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <section id="rrss">
      <!-- If I put this article block as the last one, it works -->
      <article id="instagram">
        <div data-rrss="instagram"></div>
      </article>
      <br/>
      <article id="facebook">
        <div data-rrss="facebook"></div>
      </article>
      <br/>
      <article id="twitter">
        <div data-rrss="twitter"></div>
      </article>
    </section>

    <!-- SCRIPTS -->
    <script src='scripts/data.js'></script>
    <script src='scripts/jquery.js'></script>
    <script>var customJquery = $.noConflict(true);</script>
    <script src='../magic.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**data.js**

```
var data = {
  "facebook": {
    "id": "facebook",
    "width": 0,
    "height": 0,
    "custom_style": "border:none;overflow:hidden",
    "hide_cover": false,
    "show_facepile": true,
    "small_header": false,
    "adapt_container_width": true
  },
  "twitter": {
    "id": "twitter",
    "width": 0,
    "height": 0,
    "chrome": "nofooter noscrollbar noheader", // noborders  transparent
    "tweet_limit": 0,
    "lang": "es",
    "theme": "dark",
    "link_color": "#0084b4"
  },
  "instagram": {
    "id": "123456798123467/9876543219876543",
    "hidecaption": false,
    "custom_style": "overflow:auto;",
    "max_width": 0,
    "max_height": 500
  },
  "defaults": {
    "width": 380,
    "height": 500
  }
}
```

**magic.js**

```
var rrss = customJquery('div[data-rrss]');
var conf = undefined;
var defaults = undefined;
var node = document.querySelectorAll('[data-rrss="instagram"]')[0];

customJquery.each(rrss, function(ix, it) {
    var html = '';

    var network = customJquery(it).data('rrss');

    if (network === undefined || network == null || network.length <= 0)
        return;


    conf = data[network];

    if (conf === undefined ||conf === null || conf.length <= 0)
        return;

    defaults = data['defaults'];

    //Comprobamos si existe el key y si el value tiene texto
    if(conf.id === undefined || conf.id === null || conf.id.length === 0)
        return;

    switch(network) {
        case 'facebook':
            html =  '<iframe id="iFB" src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F' + conf.id +
                        '&tabs=timeline' +
                        '&width=' + (conf.width <= 0 ? defaults.width : conf.width) +
                        '&height=' + (conf.height <= 0 ? defaults.height : conf.height) +
                        '&small_header=' + conf.small_header +
                        '&adapt_container_width=' + conf.adapt_container_width +
                        '&hide_cover=' + conf.hide_cover +
                        '&show_facepile=' + conf.show_facepile + '"' +
                        'width="' + (conf.width <= 0 ? defaults.width : conf.width) + '" ' +
                        'height="' + (conf.height <= 0 ? defaults.height : conf.height) + '" ' +
                        'style="' + conf.custom_style + '" ' +
                        'scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>\n' +
                    '<script type="text/javascript">\n' +
                    '  setInterval(() => {\n' +
                    '    customJquery("#iFB")[0].src = customJquery("#iFB")[0].src\n' +
                    '  }, 5 * 60 * 1000);\n'
                    '</script>';
        break;
        case 'twitter':
            html =  '<a class="twitter-timeline" '+
                        'href="https://twitter.com/' + conf.id + '" ' +
                        'data-width="' + (conf.width <= 0 ? defaults.width : conf.width) + '" ' +
                        'data-height="' + (conf.height <= 0 ? defaults.height : conf.height) + '" ';

            if (conf.chrome !== undefined && conf.chrome !== '') {
                html += 'data-chrome="' + conf.chrome + '" ';
            }

            if (conf.tweet_limit > 0) {
                html += 'data-tweet-limit="' + conf.tweet_limit + '" ';
            }

            html += 'data-lang="' + conf.lang + '" ' +
                    'data-theme="' + conf.theme + '" ' +
                    'data-link-color="' + conf.link_color + '"' +
                    '>Tweets by ' + conf.id + '</a>\n' +
                    '<script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>';
        break;
        case 'instagram':
            node = node.parentElement;
            html =  '<script async src="https://connect.facebook.net/es_ES/sdk.js"></script>\n' +
                    '<script src="../insta.js"></script>\n' +
                    '<script async defer src="https://www.instagram.com/embed.js"></script>\n' +
                    '<script>\n'+
                    '  setInterval(() => {\n' +
                    '    if (document.readyState === "complete") {\n' +
                    '      window.instgrm.Embeds.process();\n' +
                    '    }\n' +
                    '  }, 100);\n' +
                    '  setInterval(() => {\n' +
                    '    fbAsyncInit();\n' +
                    '  }, 5 * 60 * 1000);\n'
                    '</script>';
        break;
        default:
            html = '';
    }

    if (html != '') {
        customJquery(it).replaceWith(html);
    }
});
```

**insta.js**

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
  var html = '';
  var style = '';

  // When the Instagram's article bloke in HTML isn't the last one, this shows data from Twitter bloke
  console.log(conf);

  if (node !== undefined) {
    if (document.getElementById('instagram') !== null) {
      document.getElementById('instagram').innerHTML = '';
    }

    if (conf !== undefined && conf !== '') {
      if (conf.max_width !== undefined && conf.max_width > 0) {
        style += 'max-width: ' + conf.max_width + 'px;';
      } else {
        style += 'max-width: ' + defaults.width + 'px;';
      }

      if (conf.max_height !== undefined && conf.max_height > 0) {
        style += 'max-height: ' + conf.max_height + 'px;';
      } else {
        style += 'max-height: ' + defaults.height + 'px;';
      }

      style += conf.custom_style;
    }

    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = 'instagram';

    if (style !== '') {
      div.style = style;
    }

    node.appendChild(div);
  }

  var pageId = conf.id.substring(0, conf.id.indexOf('/'));
  var appId = conf.id.substring(conf.id.indexOf('/') + 1);

  FB.init({
    appId: appId,
    autoLogAppEvents: true,
    xfbml: true,
    version: "v3.1"
  });

  FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
    if (response.status === "connected") {
      FB.api(
        "/" + pageId + "/",
        "GET", { "fields": "instagram_business_account" },
        function (response) {
          if (response.error && response.error !== '') {
            console.log("Error recovering 'instagram_business_account': " + response.error.message);
          } else {
            FB.api(
              "/" + response.instagram_business_account.id + "/media",
              "GET", { "fields": "shortcode" },
              function (response) {
                for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
                  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

                  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                      html = JSON.parse(this.response).html;
                      document.getElementById("instagram").innerHTML += html;
                    }
                  };

                  xhttp.open("GET", "https://api.instagram.com/oembed/?url=http://instagr.am/p/" + response.data[i].shortcode + "&omitscript=true&hidecaption=" + conf.hidecaption, true);
                  xhttp.send();
                }
              }
            );
          }
        }
      );
    } else {
      console.log("Error recovering access token: Not connected.")
      console.log(response)
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Please make it as  a snippet.

Comment: Sorry, I've never use that, if there an option or you say something like Fiddle?

Comment: yes, like fiddle.

Comment: You should use the code snippet in the editor instead.

Comment: I created a Plunker, since I needed more files.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've solved with some ugly lonely line:

```
case 'instagram':
    node = node.parentElement;
    instaconf = conf; // ***** Saved the conf here *****
    html = '<script async src="https://connect.facebook.net/es_ES/sdk.js"></script>\n' +
           '<script src="../tecInsta.js"></script>\n' +
           '<script async defer src="https://www.instagram.com/embed.js"></script>\n' +
           '<script>\n'+
           '  setInterval(() => {\n' +
           '    if (document.readyState === "complete") {\n' +
           '      window.instgrm.Embeds.process();\n' +
           '    }\n' +
           '  }, 100);\n' +
           '  setInterval(() => {\n' +
           '    fbAsyncInit();\n' +
           '  }, 5 * 60 * 1000);\n'
           '</script>';
    break;
```

Then changed the `conf` references to `instaconf` in **insta.js** file.

Since this file was loaded after the *jQuery* loops ended, the configuration was the last one in that loop (the last *article* in **index.html** file).

Comment: This we cant use since object will pass by reference so it will point last object means twitter related information

Comment: No, it won't. Since `instaconf`is a global variable and only will be set when `network` is "instagram". I've checked it and works fine.

Comment: yes it will work but he is looking dynamically pick the values

Answer (score 0):

Here the problem is you are appending HTML elements dynamically. Here jquery    will append in DOM then browser will some time to parse. Until that controller wont wait for the operation so loop continue execution. so here config is hold last element of twitter configuration.

And we can't pass reference to html string as per my knowledge. This we can achieve by passing config as string into html string from there we can pass to fbAsyncInit() method.

```
                    '<script>\n'+
                '  setInterval(() => {\n' +
                '    if (document.readyState === "complete") {\n' +
                '      window.instgrm.Embeds.process();\n' +
                '    }\n' +
                '  }, 100);\n' +
                '  setInterval(() => {\n' +
                ' let configuration = '+ JSON.stringify(conf) +';'+
                '    fbAsyncInit(configuration);\n' +
                '  }, 5 * 60 * 1000);\n'
                '</script>';
```

and we can receive as

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function (con) {
```

or we can pass call back function to html method and we do operation which is done in magic.js

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function

then we can return html accordingly.

I hope this will help you.